# Can't save logs to server from my nodejs app on heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I am using heroku free account and I want to save error and access logs from my nodejs app using morgan on heroku itself.
 - Can't access the /var/logs
 - If I save it in the tree of my app, these logs get deleted on next push as heroku redeploys the app.

Is there any way to save the logs and make them persist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using papertrail or logentries. They are third-party addons and they have a free plan sufficient for you.

Heroku restarts your app once a day, so nothing is persistent. You have to save everything(logs, data, images...) to third-party addons.

Comment: Thanks @ZeroCho
I tried these two before, it works. I wanted logs to retain on the server but I guess I have no other option